# Não estou conseguindo enviar por Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-database

var inputEmail = document.getElementById('inputEmail');
var inputName = document.getElementById('inputName');
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');

//Ao clicar no botão
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    create(inputEmail.value, inputName.value);
});

function create(name, email) {
    var data = {
        name: name,
        email: email
    };
    return firebase.db().ref().child().push(data);
}

```html
<form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputName">Nome</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nome">
                      </div>
                      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block text-uppercase" id="addBtn">Acessar</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/real-time-db.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou tentnado enviar o nome e o email do usuario para o firebase DB, mas não está indo. A configuração da auth está true e todos os links e cdns estão lá.
Não sei o q está dando errado.

Comment: o auth não tem nada a ver com o Database, no seu caso, da uma confeida nesse comando firebase.db().ref().child().push(data); tente assim firebase.db().ref('/').child('users').push(data);

Comment: consegui arrumar, valeu